# Adjusting CMake compiler commands to account for weirdness

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm working with a third-party-modified version of clang 7.0.0 that has hijacked the `-c` option, replacing it with a flag `-ccdsp` for... reasons...

This has created two problems for CMake:

1. The `-ccdsp` option seems to be required to be the *very first* option to `clang`, before anything else, including `-D...` and `-I...` parameters. There is a `BEFORE` modifier for `target_compile_options` that I can use to make sure it appears at the start of the option list, but I don't seem to have any control over the ordering of non-options like definitions and include-paths, which results in `-ccdsp` occurring later in the overall set of parameters. I haven't been able to find a way to ensure that this is the very first option using modern CMake methods. Instead I have had to resort to setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` explicitly.
2. Now that the `-c` option to specify a source file is no longer available, I need to find a way to get CMake to omit it. It turns out that, as far as I can tell, this flag isn't really required, as `clang -c foo.cpp -o foo.o` and `clang foo.cpp -o foo.o` appear to do much the same thing. So I need a way to get CMake to drop the `-c` option.

I realise that this is an unusual question and it's a situation entirely created by the organisation that provided the modified version of clang. Unfortunately my support requests to them remain (to date) unanswered.

Does anyone know of a way I can work around this issue? Can I create a custom compiler handler in CMake, based on clang, where I add `-ccdsp` and remove `-c` somehow?

Comment: Are you more interested in CMake options or in making the situation work?

Comment: Primarily I'd like to know if there's a way to customise CMake to handle these situations, however I've also implemented a workaround where I wrap the clang compiler in a script that rewrites the command line. It works for the moment, but it's a nasty hack. Ideally I'd like to increase my knowledge of CMake so that I can solve this kind of thing in the future.

Comment: OK. That sort of script was the only workaround I could think of. ;)

Answer (score 4):

In CMake a compiler's command line is specified in [CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILE_OBJECT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILE_OBJECT.html) variable.

You may set this variable in a separate file:

**my_clang_override.cmake**:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_OBJECT "<CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER> -ccdsp <FLAGS> -o <OBJECT>")
```

and include this file into the project's `CMakeLists.txt` by specifying [CMAKE_USER_MAKE_RULES_OVERRIDE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_USER_MAKE_RULES_OVERRIDE.html) variable with either of two ways:

1. Specify the variable in the `CMakeLists.txt` itself, **before** the `project()` call:

   **CMakeLists.txt**:

   ```
    # Assume file 'my_clang_override.cmake' to be in the project's source directory.
    set(CMAKE_USER_MAKE_RULES_OVERRIDE "my_clang_override.cmake")
   ```
2. Pass the variable's setting to `cmake` when configure the project:

   ```
   cmake -DCMAKE_USER_MAKE_RULES_OVERRIDE=<path/to/my_clang_override.cmake> <other-parameters>
   ```